# Debian + Linux kernel 3.12.22: “Kernel module loader” option is not available

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, options

The Debian guide for compiling a kernel [says](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch08s06.html.en):

*Do not forget to select “Kernel module loader” in “Loadable module support” (it is not selected by default). If not included, your Debian installation will experience problems.*

However, I have downloaded the 3.12.22 kernel, run *make xconfig* and searched for the “Kernel module loader” option without finding it.  Has such option been discontinued, included by default, or not needed anymore?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts of this guide are seriously out of date.

“Loadable module support” is the name of the option that enables `kmod`, the kernel component that calls `modprobe` to load modules with a symbolic name based on hardware identification. You can see these symbolic names in `/lib/modules/VERSION/modules.alias`; they're automatically extracted from the kernel sources. For example the line `alias pci:v00001002d00005147sv*sd*bc*sc*i* radeonfb` means that when the kernel requests a module whose name is of the form `pci:v00001002d00005147sv*sd*bc*sc*i*` then `modprobe` will look for a file called `radeonfb.ko`. The symbolic name corresponds to a particular PCI identifier which is sent by the PCI peripheral (in this case, a video card).

The thing is, “loadable module support” is the name of the option [in kernel 2.4.x](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/35-how-to-add-a-loadable-kernel-module/). In 2.6, the option was renamed “Automatic kernel module loading” (for the internal name `CONFIG_KMOD`). In [version 2.6.27](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/init/Kconfig?v=2.6.27), the kmod feature became a compulsory part of module support, and the option was removed soon after since it was ignored.